# send object from node to express.static (react app)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

i have a express server like this

```
app.use(['/home', '/'], express.static('dist', { maxAge: cacheTime}));
```

dist is my folder where i build my react app, everthing works fine but now i need to know the enviroment where the app is so i thought i could get that with

```
process.env.NODE_ENV
```

however i don't know if it's posible to send that value to my react app i've been doing a lot of research on google but i can't find anything yet

any suggestions?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the server locally or on a hosted service?

If you are running it locally, you have to set the node environment yourself.
Install the dotenv npm package and setup your `.env` file
`process.env.NODE_ENV` is a reference to the `NODE_ENV` value in your `.env` file

If you are running it on the hosted service, `process.env.NODE_ENV` should get the environment of the service, which is likely to be "production". Or you should check out the documentation on their NodeJS support.